# How to change units and scale of a shapefile?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, scale

I have a polyline shapefile, the default unit is in meters and its length is 117m. Is there a way I can make its length 117km? Like I change the scale of my shapefile?

I want this line to appear to be the same size, only scale up the units:
[image]

Answer (score 8):

If you want to increase the size of a feature, you can use the [Scale tool](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/editing-existing-features/scaling-a-feature.htm) in ArcMap. It's an Editor tool but it's not on the toolbar by default, you'll need to add it using the Customize option for toolbars. It can be found under the Editor category:

[image]

You can scale up your features by a Scale Factor by selecting your features, activating the Scale tool, pressing 'F', then entering your scale factor (1000 in your case). If you want to do it for an entire shapefile, just select all the features in the shapefile and Scale them at once with the same scale factor. You will probably need to fiddle around with the Anchor Point (the origin point your features are scaled from) to get the exact result you want.

Comment: The only downside of scaling, is if the road was in a coordinate system that used Meters and fitted the road in an aerial base map, Scaling the road  may throw off how well it fits other datasets. Scaling works great with data from a CAD system drawn at a scale but not GIS data in a coordinate system.